# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my dequeue function, it wont remove anything from the queue or output after running it

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, queue, abstraction

Implementing a queue using imperative programming, i tried introducing a dequeue function but it's not working, Check for errors please .

```
queue = [None for index in range(0, 10)]

rearPointer = -1
frontPointer = 0
queueFull = 10
queueLength = 0

def Dequeue():
    global queueLength, frontPointer, Item
    if queueLength == 0:
        print("Queue is empty, cannot dequeue")
    else:
        #item = queue[frontPointer]
        if frontPointer == (len(queue) - 1):
            frontPointer = 0
        else:
            frontPointer += 1
    queueLength -= 1
```

Comment: Why are you trying to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it makes no sense to implement this when already exist a deque object. except just as an excersise.

```
from collections import deque

queue = [index for index in range(0, 10)]
my_deque = deque(queue)
```

Now you can use popleft and pop to dequeue

```
print(queue)
>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for _ in range(3):
    out = my_deque.popleft()
    print(out)
>>>
0
1
2

for _ in range(3):
    out = my_deque.pop()
    print(out)
>>>
9
8
7
```

If you want to implement this yourself Sparkling Marcel is correct, his answer is giving you everything you need. Your functions should look like this:

```py
def Dequeueleft(queue, number=1):
    if len(queue) == 0:
        print("Queue is empty, cannot dequeue")
    values = []
    for _ in range(number):
        val = queue[0]
        queue = queue[1:]
        values.append(val)
    return queue, values

# equivalent fucntion
def Dequeueleft(queue, number=1):
    if len(queue) == 0:
        print("Queue is empty, cannot dequeue")
    values = [val for val in queue[:number]]
    return queue[number:], values
```

output

```
queue = [index for index in range(0, 10)]
queue, vals = Dequeueleft(queue, 2)
print(queue, vals)
>>> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] [0, 1]
```

Comment: Its actually a highschool assignment and the syllabus says we should be able to make it ourselves without using any libraries that is why i tried making that function, Thank you for the final answer

Comment: and also i cannot use the list.append() methods and pop methods

Comment: OK now I get a bit more your answer. If you have any question let me know. If not you can accept the answer as valid

Answer (score 0):

You're actually never removing any item from your list in your dequeue function, ence why it does nothing

All you're really doing right now is changing   `queueLength` and `frontPointer`
value, but never touching `queue` itself

What you would want to do is simply removing the first element of your list (aka `queue`)

And then move every item one place before, so the earlier 2nd element becomes first

Comment: Could you demonstrate it with your own code please ?